# How to speed up file reading using SharePoint CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml, file

I have created a function using the SharePoint CSOM to extract all files within a Document Collection (List) using the below code however it takes over 5 minutes to get a list of 3671 files.

Is it possible to speed this up and if so How? I've seen other people use CAML Queries to extract files from a folder although I'm not 100% sure on how I would implement that.

```
    static SharePointOnlineCredentials SPCreds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("*********", new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "*******").SecurePassword);
    static string sharepointURL = "https://********";
    static string ListName = "Documents";
    static string docuemntsStartWith = "Shared Documents";

    static List<string> files = new List<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(sharepointURL))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = SPCreds;
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);                
            clientContext.Load(list);
            getFilesInFolder(clientContext, list.RootFolder);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Extracted all " + files.Count + " files");
        Console.Read();
        foreach(string f in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("DONE");

        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void getFilesInFolder(ClientContext cc, SP.Folder SPFolder)
    {
        cc.Load(SPFolder);
        cc.Load(SPFolder.Folders);
        cc.Load(SPFolder.Files);
        cc.ExecuteQuery();
        FolderCollection fcol = SPFolder.Folders;
        FileCollection filecol = SPFolder.Files;
        foreach (SP.File SPF in filecol)
        {
            files.Add(SPF.ServerRelativeUrl);
        }

        foreach (SP.Folder SPF in fcol)
        {
            getFilesInFolder(cc, SPF);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need the urls of the files, and not the content, you can use the following code for your `getFilesInFolder` method and it should do the trick:

```
public static void getFilesInFolder(List list)
{
    CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
    query.ViewXml   = "<View Scope=\"Recursive\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\" /><Value Type=\"Number\">0</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

    var items = list.GetItems(query);
    list.Context.Load(items);
    list.Context.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (var SPF in items)
    {
        files.Add(SPF.FieldValues["FileRef"].ToString());
    }
}
```